Issue 429 error code after 12h when calling "login.microsoftonline.../well-known" to refresh token to call Azure SQL Database from Azure App Service
I have an Azure App Service that is called multiple times per second.
This App Service connects to an Azure SQL Database using a managed identity.
The application works correctly for about 12 hours, but then I start seeing calls to "login.microsoftonline.../well-known..." that either time out or take a very long time.
This causes significant slowdowns because subsequent incoming requests also seem to try calling this URL to retrieve a refresh token, and all of them then take more than 30 seconds to complete and i have 429 http error code.
I don’t have any specific configuration in the code since, as far as I know, everything related to the refresh token should be handled automatically by the library.
Does someone had this problem too? Thank you
    private static void ConfigureAzureIdentityAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var userAssignedManagedIdentity = configuration.GetValue<string?>("UserAssignedManagedIdentity");

    //Managed Identities handlers - User Assigned Managed Identity
    services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAssignedManagedIdentity))
        {
            DefaultAzureCredential defaultAzureCredential = new(
                new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                {
                    ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedManagedIdentity
                });

            clientBuilder.UseCredential(defaultAzureCredential);
        }
    });
}




Instead of image please share code in text format

Managed identities use Azure AD tokens to authenticate. These tokens have a limited lifetime of one hour and must be refreshed before expiry.

Yes for the managed identity token but i have this issue with adresses "login.mocrosoftonline....", i have updated my post

Please look up what HTTP status code 429 means.

I know what 429 http code means...
But what i don't understand is that the the library is supposed to handle this, I believe. It should prevent all calls from the same application from repeatedly requesting a refresh token.
I imagine there must be some kind of "lock" mechanism to manage this, right?
Or is there a manual solution for handling this that I’m unaware of?


Issue 429 error code after 12h when calling "login.microsoftonline.../well-known" to refresh token to call Azure SQL Database from Azure App Service

Try with the below code it uses DefaultAzureCredential which automatically handles token refreshes internally and also avoids frequent requests. Enable pooling in connection string so, only the first connection in the pool triggers a token request. async/await in the code uses asynchronous programming for opening connections and executing queries. By this application can handle a high volume of requests.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddConsole(); 
                })
                .ConfigureAzureServices(configuration)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var sqlService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SqlService>();

            await sqlService.ExecuteQueryAsync("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables");

            Console.WriteLine("Query executed successfully!");
        }
    }

    public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        private static DefaultAzureCredential _azureCredential;

        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAzureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _azureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            services.AddTransient(sp =>
            {
                var connectionString = BuildConnectionString(configuration);
                var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<SqlConnection>>();

                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                sqlConnection.StateChange += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("SQL Connection state changed: {State}", args.CurrentState);
                };
                return sqlConnection;
            });
            services.AddTransient<SqlService>();
            return services;
        }
        
        private static string BuildConnectionString(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            return new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = configuration["AzureSql:Server"],
                InitialCatalog = configuration["AzureSql:Database"],
                Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity,
                ConnectTimeout = 30,
                Pooling = true
            }.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
    
    public class SqlService
    {
        private readonly SqlConnection _sqlConnection;
        private readonly ILogger<SqlService> _logger;

        public SqlService(SqlConnection sqlConnection, ILogger<SqlService> logger)
        {
            _sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task ExecuteQueryAsync(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Opening SQL connection...");
                    await _sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                }

                using var command = new SqlCommand(query, _sqlConnection);
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                _logger.LogInformation("Query executed successfully.");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "SQL error occurred.");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                await _sqlConnection.CloseAsync();
            }
        }

Output
Opening SQL connection... 
Query executed successfully!

